# Grails dbm-update & change_log changesets: transactional or not?

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

I was under the impression that changesets within migration scripts were transactional, but I am seeing that in practice they are not.

For the simplest example of this, create a basic changeset entry, maybe as follows:

```
changeSet(author: "some_email@server.com", id: "1-1", description: "An example changeset for a changelog.groovy.") {
    createTable(tableName: "table_name") {
        column(autoIncrement: "true", name: "id", type: "BIGINT") {
            constraints(nullable: "false", primaryKey: "true")
        }

        column(name: "version", type: "BIGINT") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "name", type: "VARCHAR(64)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

        column(name: "name", type: "VARCHAR(64)") {
            constraints(nullable: "false")
        }

    }
```

}

Now, obviously we cannot add two columns of the same name, so this should fail - and rollback. But it doesn't rollback. The table is created and the first column is added - despite the fact it is a "bad" changeset.

So, the questions are -

1) are changelog.groovy changesets transactions?

2) is grails dmb-update supposed to execute changesets transactionally?

3) if so, what did we configure incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you under the impression they are? They aren't.

Comment: Because I was told they were. LOL! But, ok - they aren't. Thank you. If you add an answer, I will mark it complete.

Comment: The issue with them not being transactional is if a large changeset is run but fails, then dbm-rollback also does not work to remove the "bad" change. Thus, you must manually update the tables/columns/FKs, etc before a corrected dbm-update can be applied. Given Grails' automatic nature, this seems uncharacteristic.

Comment: The primary issue is that transactions, rollback, etc. are primarily a data/DML concept. Some databases have at least partial support for rolling back structural/DDL changes, but it's very impractical in the general case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database migrations in Grails are not transactional. If you need the ability to rollback a failed changeset you have to write the rollback yourself.

As Burt points out "The primary issue is that transactions, rollback, etc. are primarily a data/DML concept. Some databases have at least partial support for rolling back structural/DDL changes, but it's very impractical in the general case".